# Generate k unique random numbers in the interval [0,n-1]?

Tags: c++, performance, random

How can I generate k unique random numbers in the interval [0,n-1]?

I used the following code:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i ){
   a[i]=i;
}

std::random_shuffle( a, a+n ) ;
for(int i=0;i<k;++i){
  ra[i]=a[i];
}
```

which takes first k elements.

Can anyone refer me to a faster approach?

std::random_shuffle:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/

Comment: I don't think there is a faster way unless you are looking to generate numbers outside the range you have choosen

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating m distinct random numbers in the range \[0..n-1\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947612/generating-m-distinct-random-numbers-in-the-range-0-n-1)

Answer (score 1):

For small values of `n` your method is well suited. Of course, you can mix elements of the array manually, but this is unlikely to be much faster.

For large values you can use the [Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator):

```
r[n + 1] = (a * r[n] + c) % m;
```

Where `m` (modulus) is equal to your `n`.
To maximize the length of generated sequence you should to follow some rules when choosing values `a` and `c` (see link above for details).

Of course, `k` should me smaller than `n`.