# Picking 6 random unique numbers

Tags: c++

I have a problem trying to get this to work. I am meant to be picking 6 unique numbers between 1 & 49. I have a function doing this correctly but struggling to check the array for the duplicate and replacing.

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL))); // Seeds a random number
int picked[6];
int number,i,j;
const int MAX_NUMBERS = 6;

for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBERS; i++)
{
    number = numberGen();
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_NUMBERS; j++)
    {
        if (picked[i] == picked[j])
        {
            picked[j] = numberGen();
        }
    }

}
```

My number generator just creates a random number between 1 & 49 which i think works ok. I have just started on C++ and any help would be great

```
int numberGen()
{
 int number = rand();
 int target = (number % 49) + 1;

 return target;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating m distinct random numbers in the range \[0..n-1\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947612/generating-m-distinct-random-numbers-in-the-range-0-n-1)

Comment: If we're speaking about C++, `std::set` are much better at checking existing  values and there is a separate sub-library for [RNG](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: Where does `number` go? Why are you intending to replace already-generated numbers with a new generated number?

Comment: @DanielA.White, OP question is about code not working. Linked question is about efficiency of algorithms.

Comment: I have glanced at sets but we haven't covered this in our course material yet so i cannot use this unfortunately @Thebluefish

Comment: One easy option: stick the numbers 1-49 in a vector. `std::shuffle` the vector. Grab the first 6 numbers.

Comment: @Thebluefish Apologies, i must have removed when i was trying things out.  Number is plugged into picked[i]

Comment: really good example of what @JesperJuhl is talking about in [this documentation for `std::iota`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks, i believe we are covering vectors next week and are meant to solve with arrays

Comment: @James Fogarty - vector or array makes no difference in this case. Stuff the values into a `std::array`. Shuffle it. Read the first 6 values - works just as well for this.

Comment: @JamesFogarty If you have worked out an algorithm for solving your program, you should explain it. If you haven't worked out an algorithm, you should explain what you're stuck on working out an algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

## C++17 sample

C++17 provides an algorithm for exactly this (go figure):

[std::sample](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample)

> ```
> template< class PopulationIterator, class SampleIterator,
>           class Distance, class UniformRandomBitGenerator >
> SampleIterator sample( PopulationIterator first, PopulationIterator last,
>                        SampleIterator out, Distance n, 
>                        UniformRandomBitGenerator&& g);
> ```
>
> (since C++17)
>
> Selects n elements from the sequence [first; last) such that each
>   possible sample has equal probability of appearance, and writes those
>   selected elements into the output iterator out. Random numbers are
>   generated using the random number generator g. [...]

```
constexpr int min_value = 1;
constexpr int max_value = 49;
constexpr int picked_size = 6;

constexpr int size = max_value - min_value + 1;

// fill array with [min value, max_value] sequence
std::array<int, size> numbers{};
std::iota(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), min_value);

// select 6 radom
std::array<int, picked_size> picked{};
std::sample(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), picked.begin(), picked_size,
            std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
```

## C++11 shuffle

If you can't use C++17 yet then the way to do this is to generate all the numbers in an array, shuffle the array and then pick the first 6 numbers in the array:

```
// fill array with [min value, max_value] sequence
std::array<int, size> numbers{};
std::iota(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), min_value);

// shuffle the array
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 e{rd()};

std::shuffle(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), e);

// (optional) copy the picked ones:

std::array<int, picked_size> picked{};
std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.begin() + picked_size, picked.begin());
```

A side note: please use the new C++11 random library. And prefer `std::array` to bare C arrays. They don't decay to pointers and provide `begin`, `end`, `size` etc. methods.

---

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this code down.

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBERS; i++)
```

We're doing a for-loop with 6 iterations.

```
number = numberGen();
```

We're generating a new number, and storing it into the variable `number`. This variable isn't used anywhere else.

```
for (int j = 0; j < MAX_NUMBERS; j++)
```

We're looping through the array again...

```
    if (picked[i] == picked[j])
```

Checking to see if the two values match (fyi, `picked[n] == picked[n]` will **always** match)

```
        picked[j] = numberGen();
```

And assigning a new random number to the *existing* value if they do match.

A better approach here would be to eliminate a duplicate value if one exists, *then* assign it to your array. For example:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBERS; i++)
{
    bool isDuplicate = false;

    do
    {
        number = numberGen(); // Generate the number

        // Check for duplicates
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_NUMBERS; j++)
        {
            if (number == picked[j])
            {
                isDuplicate = true;
                break; // Duplicate detected
            }
        }
    }
    while (isDuplicate); // equivalent to while(isDuplicate == true)

    picked[j] = number;
}
```

Here, we run a do-while loop. The first iteration of the loop will generate a random number, and checks to see if it's a duplicate already in the array. If it is, it re-runs the loop until a non-duplicate is found. Once the loop breaks, we have a valid, non-duplicate number available, and then we assign it to the array.

There are going to be better solutions available as you progress through your course.

Answer (score 0):

#### Efficient approach: Limited Fisher–Yates shuffle

For drawing n numbers from a pool of m you need n calls to random for this approach (6 in your case) instead of m-1 (49 in your case) used when simply shuffling the whole array or vector. So **the approach shown below is much more efficient than simply shuffling the whole array** and **does not require any duplicate checking**.

1. random numbers can get really expensive, so I thought it might be a good idea never to generate more random numbers than necessary. Simply running rand() multiple times until a fitting number comes out seems no good idea.
2. repetitive double check drawing gets especially expensive in the case that nearly all of the available numbers need to be drawn
3. I wanted to do it stateful, so it doesn´t matter how many numbers of the 49 you actually request

The solution below does not do any duplicate checking and calls rand() exactly n times for n random numbers. A slight modification of your numberGen was necessary therefore. Albeit you really should use the random library functions instead of rand().

The code below draws all numbers, just to verify that everything works fine, but its easy to see how you would draw only 6 numbers :-)

If you need repetitive draws you can simply add a reset() member function that sets `drawn = 0` again. The vector is in shuffled state then, but that doesn´t do any harm.

If you can´t afford the range checking in `std::vector.at()` you can of course easily replace it by the index access operator[]. But I thought for experimenting with the code at() is a better choice and in this way you get error checking for the case that too many numbers are drawn.

**Usage:**
Create a class instance of n_out_of_m using the constructor which takes as an argument the amount of available numbers.

Call draw() repetitively to draw numbers.

If you call draw() more often then numbers are available the std::vector.at() will throw an out_of_range exception, if you don´t like that you need to add a check for that case.

I hope someone likes this approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

size_t numberGen(size_t limit)
{
    size_t number = rand();
    size_t target = (number % limit) + 1;
    
    return target;
}

class n_out_of_m {
public:
           n_out_of_m(int m) {numbers.reserve(m); for(int i=1; i<=m; ++i) numbers.push_back(i);}
    int    draw();
private:
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    size_t drawn = 0;
};

int n_out_of_m::draw()
{
    size_t index = numberGen(numbers.size()-drawn) - 1;
    std::swap(numbers.at(index), numbers.at(numbers.size()-drawn-1));
    drawn++;
    return numbers.at(numbers.size()-drawn);
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    n_out_of_m my_gen(49);
    for(int n=0; n<49; ++n)
       std::cout << n << "\t" << my_gen.draw() << "\n";
        
    return 0;
}
```