# Randomly fill 100 grid of 100X100 matrix by 1

Tags: c, random, probability

I have a matrix for `M[100][100]`, all filled with `ZERO`. Now I want to fill randomly 100 grids by '1'. How do I do that?

***Challenge I am facing:***

When I randomly select any position `(x, y)`, that position can be already filled by 1. I have to minimise `rand()` call count. Is it possible to fill within `100` `rand()` call limit?

The question was marked as duplicated with [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947612) but that does not solve my problem? Any generalised idea for 2D matrix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating m distinct random numbers in the range \[0..n-1\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947612/generating-m-distinct-random-numbers-in-the-range-0-n-1)

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch, but use the question i marked as a duplicate for the 100 indices you'd like to set to `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Fisher-Yates solution [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6947853/918959). Specifically you'd want to *once* create an array that contains numbers 0 ... 9999, where `x = i % 100` and `y = i / 100`, say.

Or if you want, you could as well use an array of `struct coords { char x, y; }`.

Then you shuffle only the first (or last) 100 elements, after which those first (last) 100 elements will be your coordinates. You can reuse the same array without subsequent initialization. Each 100 random fillings require only exactly 100 random numbers being generated.